# How to spawn a empty UIimage view programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview, uiimage

Is there a simple way to spawn an empty UIImage view programmatically without having to have an the code to add an image into the actual image view

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create the imageView.
And you can set a background colors to be sure there is the image view.

```
let imageview: UIImageView = {
    let img = UIImageView()
    img.backgroundColor = .red
    img.translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
    return img
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubView(imageView)
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
}
```